# What is the point of adding an exclamation mark before git add?

Tags: git, bash

I'm looking at the dotfile for git aliases [here](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles/blob/master/.gitconfig#L22). Why is there an exclamation mark before the `git add`? And looking at other aliases, quite a few use `!`, in the formal of `$alias_name$ = "!..."`. Are the two uses different?

I looked up some bash uses of `!` and it seems to be used to get previous commands, but this use seems to be different. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Aliases#Advanced

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`!` is not before `git add`, it's before the entire command line. It means "run the command with a shell". Git aliases are usually simple substitutions:

```
[alias]
ca = commit -a
```

means that the command `git ca` will be interpreted by git as `git commit -a`.

For more complex tricks in aliases people use shell commands and functions, and `!` calls shell. For the alias you pointed to it means that `git ca` will execute

```
git add -A && git commit -av
```

in a shell.

Answer (score 1):

The '!' is used to tell that the command that is between the double quotes is not a git command. 
The command will use one of the many command line executable installed on your system.

Indeed, you could call the git executable, so that this 2 alias are the same :

```
 st = "status" 

 st = "!git status"
```